# Use of downloaded data from data.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, tags, data-dump

I'm curious about data provided publicly by data.stackexchange.com. It is also available at archive.org. Can I use it for professional purpose? I would like to use only tag names.

Comment: If you want a precise answer, you will need to define "professional purposes". But, in general, you can use the data however you like, as long as you provide attribution.

Comment: "Professional purposes" means in personal web application. And what do you mean by provide attribution?

Comment: See the footer: all contributions to this site are licensed under CC by-SA: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/. Attribution means you have to give credit to the source. That would be the person who posted the question or answer.

Comment: It means that I've to mention data.stackexchange.com as source, in my application. Then I can use tag names freely. Am I right? and where to provide attribution? in terms & conditions?

Comment: related, if not a duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68672/data-dump-torrent-required-attribution

Comment: FYI: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232085/my-project-requires-data-from-stack-overflow-what-can-i-do/232086#232086

Comment: Thank you both for help. Now I got it.